# i have some thing with my servlet page

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

Hello I have this code in a servlet in netbeans and I have a problem that when I login as a valid user or invalid it keeps this url `localhost:8080/LogIN123/login`.
The login is the servlet and it doesn't response for the next page.

Can anyone help me?

The program must enter the username and password, then if the `Id` for user are the same for supervisor it will resend to another page
that has employee under him and if he is just an employee it will redirect him to a page that have information about him without editing.

```
public class login extends HttpServlet {

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "employee";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "root";

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String name;
        String pass;
        Connection conn;
        Statement Stmt;
        ResultSet rs;

        try {

            name = request.getParameter("username");
            pass = request.getParameter("password");


            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
            Stmt = conn.createStatement();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from emp_info where username=? && password=?");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

**here I have class name userbean that contanis the data from the data base**

```
            UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
```

**and here a listof beans that will be sends to the other pages it contains the user info**

```
            List<UserBean> listOfUserBean = new ArrayList<UserBean>();

            if (rs.next()) {
                userBean.setUserID(rs.getString("id"));
                userBean.setUserName(rs.getString("username"));
                userBean.setUserGender(rs.getString("gender"));
                userBean.setUserSupervisour(rs.getString("supervisour"));
                userBean.setUserBirthDay(rs.getString("BirthOfDate"));
                userBean.setUserSalary(rs.getString("salary"));
            }

            listOfUserBean.add(userBean);

            response.sendRedirect("mangerpage.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("userlist", listOfUserBean);
```

**the code below checks if the user id are the same supervisor it means that he is the manager of some employee and he will get new page that show all employees under his management**

```
            if (userBean.getUserID().equals(userBean.getUserSupervisour())) {
                Stmt = conn.createStatement();
                PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement("select * from emp_info where supervisour=?");
                ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();

                if (rs2.next()) {
                    userBean.setUserID(rs2.getString("id"));
                    userBean.setUserName(rs2.getString("username"));
                    userBean.setUserGender(rs2.getString("gender"));
                    userBean.setUserSupervisour(rs2.getString("supervisour"));
                    userBean.setUserBirthDay(rs2.getString("BirthOfDate"));
                    userBean.setUserSalary(rs2.getString("salary"));
                }

                listOfUserBean.add(userBean);
                request.setAttribute("userlist",listOfUserBean);
                response.sendRedirect("mangerpage.jsp");
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("userlist",listOfUserBean);
                request.setAttribute("name", name);
                response.sendRedirect("mypage.jsp");
            }

            if (userBean.getUserID().equals("")) {
                response.sendRedirect("flogin.jsp");
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please 1) trim down your code to the parts necessary to reproduce your question, 2) explain in more detail what behaviour you expect and how the actual behaviour differs.

Comment: You mean to say that it is not navigating to jsp's which are mentioned in your code?

Comment: yes it dosenot redrict the user to the onther page it gives me just ablank page

Answer (score 0):

You must have mapped your servlet to action `login`.

I think you are not redirecting to your JSP properly.

`response.sendRedirect("mangerpage.jsp");` you should be giving either the absolute path or proper relative path.

For relative path will need to see your directory structure for commenting.

Have a look at [this](http://www.servletworld.com/examples/response-sendredirect-servlet.html).

Comment: i guess the problem will be in code not in the redirect 
the redirect are correct i test it

Answer (score 0):

Since you are redirecting to the page before setting the attributes it is showing blank maybe because the list is null.

Just set the `userlist` attribute **before** you re-direct to the `managerpage.jsp`

```
request.setAttribute("userlist", listOfUserBean);
response.sendRedirect("mangerpage.jsp");
```

You can check on the page if the userlist is null or not.